# Intuition for definition of product topology (Topology: A categorical approach)

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> We want to put topology on a set $X$ formed by union of many other topological spaces indexed by $X_{\alpha}$ $$X = \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$$
>
> We can take the product topology on $X$ is defined to be the topology generated by the basis $B=\{ \prod_{\alpha \in A} U_{\alpha} | U_{\alpha} \subset X_{\alpha} $ is open and all but finitely many $U_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha} \}$

I can't seem to understand the "open and all but finitely many" part. Could someone break down what the book is saying a bit more?

Comment: It is the smallest (coarsest) topology that makes the projections $p_\alpha: X \to X_\alpha$ continuous. You could think of it (**very**) loosely as a weak topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that all $U_{\alpha}$ have to be open, but only finetely many of them can be anything other than $X_{\alpha}$.

For for example if you have an infinite product $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ a product like

$(0,1)\times (-1,2) \times \mathbb{R} \times (1,2) \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$

will be open, because only the first, second and fourth sets in the product are not $\mathbb{R}$ and the rest is. On the other hand something like $(0,1) \times (0,1) \times \cdots$ isn't open because infinitely many of the intervals are not $\mathbb{R}$.

I hope it is clear. It is actually fairly simple once you realise what the "all but finitely many" means.

Comment: I think I understand now, but could you also explain to me why this condition is put? I can't seem to understand it's significance

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I think the main reason is to make the topology the minimal for which all the projections are continuous. If your topology has less opens than those, some of the projections will cease to be continuous. In my opinion it is a much more intuitive definition. One can then prove that that topology is precisely the product topology.

The other thing to note is that there is the famous Tychonov's theorem. stating that product of compacts is compact. If you chose the topology with which the opens are simply products of opens this theorem would fail.

Answer (score 1):

We say $E\in \mathcal{B}$ if and only if it equals a product $E=\prod_{\alpha\in A}U_{\alpha}$ such that each $U_{\alpha}$ is open in $X_{\alpha}$, and such that the set of indices $\{\alpha\in A\,:\, U_{\alpha}\neq X_{\alpha}\}$ is a finite set.

More generally, suppose we have a statement $P(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$. We say $P(\alpha)$ holds for all but finitely many $\alpha$ in $A$ if and only if the set $\{\alpha\in A\,: \, \neg P(\alpha)\}$ is a finite set (that's literally the translation into symbols of the phrase "for all **but** finitely many"). For example, if the index set $A$ is finite, this always happens, so this phrase is something you only have to worry about when $A$ is an infinite set.

Comment: What is actually the idea behind this condition..? I get what it is I think but I don't get why it is put

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I find it much more natural (though of course slightly longer) to first understand the following concepts. First, the *topology generated by a collection of sets* $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$; this is defined as the smallest topology on $X$ which contains $\mathcal{S}$. Next, you have to understand the concept of *initial topology* (i.e you have a set $X$, and a collection of maps $f_{\alpha}:X\to X_{\alpha}$, where $X_{\alpha}$ are topological spaces; then the question is what's the smallest topology on $X$ which makes each $f_{\alpha}$ continuous).

Comment: In the case of $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_{\alpha}$, we have the obvious projections $\pi_{\alpha}:X\to X_{\alpha}$. So, the definition of product topology on $X$ is as the initial topology on $X$ generated by the collection of projection maps $\{\pi_{\alpha}:X\to X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$. For more details, you should either ask a separate question (or look on MSE; there are definitely good answers already on this site).

Comment: Thanks for the help peek-a-boo! I think I'll need a second look at this. I'll try again tommorrow ^^